# Open ion-datetime in local timezone

Tags: ionic-framework, timezone

I've got an Ionic app that dynamically creates a form that sometimes has an ion-datetime in it. The date time is also optional on the form, so it is not have an initial value set by me.

```
<ion-datetime *ngIf="question_definition.component == 'date'"
     displayFormat="DD MMM, YYYY HH:mm"
     pickerFormat="DD MMM YYYY HH:mm"
     [formControlName]="question_definition.question">
</ion-datetime>
```

Currently when a user taps on the element the data picker appears and is set to the time using UTC. I'm in New Zealand and want it to use +12:00 time (at the moment, until daylight saving starts).

How do I get an ion-datetime without a value to open up and display the time in my local timezone?

Answer (score 3):

After digging alot... Found answer.

**ion-datetime** apparently has an undocumented attribute called **initialValue**. So, if you want to get a different timezone, you can do this

.html

```
<ion-datetime [initialValue]="myInitialTime" pickerFormat="HH:mm" [(ngModel)]="myTime"></ion-datetime>
```

.ts

```
this.myInitialTime = localDate
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it when you start the `formController` with a `new Date ()`, in this way it will take the local time of the device.

Ex: `question: new Date()`

Comment: By using "new Date()" it sets the value for the input. The question is optional so if the user hasn't tapped on the interface the value should still be null/blank.